# how to fix Postgres error: bind message supplies 8 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 6

Tags: node.js, postgresql, vue.js, axios

Im preparing my model in my backend
i have tab1 containg id and col : t1 i want to insert into that table first then get its id and insert it into my tab2 along side with other col. So id_tab2 is my foreign key from tab1(tab 2 has its own id ofc not id_tab2)
this is the file where I declare my query :

```
const createUser=(req, res, next) => {
  let con=req.con
let { t1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,id_tab2 } = req.body;
  con.query(
`SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE x3 = $1`,
[x3],
(err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).json({message: err});
  }

  if (results.rows.length > 0) {
     res.status(404).json({message: "user exists"});
  } else {

  const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(x4, parseInt(process.env.BCRYPT_ROUNDS));
  con.query('WITH ins1 AS ( INSERT INTO tab1(t1)  VALUES ($1) RETURNING id AS id_tab2), ins2 AS ( INSERT INTO tab2 (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,id_tab2)  SELECT $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,id_tab2 FROM ins1  RETURNING id,x1, x2,x3, x4, x5,x6,id_tab2)  SELECT x1, x2,x3, x4, x5,x6,id_tab2 from ins2',
  [t1,x1, x2,x3, x4,hashedPassword,x6,id_tab2 ],
      (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(404).json( {message: err});
        }
        else
        {res.status(200).send(results.rows[0])}
      }
    );
  }
}
 );
}
```

when i do my api call from my Vue front :
here's the file :

```
axios.post("/accnt/register",data)
  .then((res)=>{
   this.$emit("addedUser",res.data)
    message.success(`user added`)
  })
.catch((e)=>{
    message.warning(e.response.data.message)
  }) 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
```

I get back this error in server side :

```
error: bind message supplies 8 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 6
.
.
.
.
.
routine: 'exec_bind_message'
```

I don't know what i did wrong in this query any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually changed the code to this and it works fine thanks to @jjanes answer I get more into the parameters and focused on them:

```
const createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  let con=req.con
  let { t1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 } = req.body; // deleted id_tab2
  con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE x3 = $1`, [x3], (err, results) => {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(404).json({message: err});
     }

     if (results.rows.length > 0) {
        res.status(404).json({message: "user exists"});
     } else {

       const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(x4, parseInt(process.env.BCRYPT_ROUNDS));
       con.query('WITH 
            ins1 AS ( 
              INSERT INTO tab1(t1)  
              VALUES ($1) 
              RETURNING id AS id_tab2
            ), 
            ins2 AS ( 
              INSERT INTO tab2 (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,id_tab2)  
              SELECT $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,id_tab2 
              FROM ins1  
              RETURNING id, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, id_tab2
            )  
            SELECT x1, x2,x3, x4, x5,x6,id_tab2 from ins2',
          [t1,x1, x2,x3, x4,hashedPassword,x6], // deleted id_tab2
          (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              res.status(404).json( {message: err});
            }
            else {
              res.status(200).send(results.rows[0])
            }
          });
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement only has 6 place holders, but your call has 8 parameters.  The error message seems self-explanatory.

You didn't say what you wanted to happen here very clearly, see we'll have to guess about your intentions.  You use `$1` twice, but based on the names of the columns you use it for, you should probably renumber to have $1 through $7, and each one only used once, rather than $1 through $6 with one of them used twice.  Also, it looks like id_tab2 is supposed to be generated by the database from a sequence, but then why are you trying to pass in a value for it?  If you renumber the parameters, and remove id_tab2 from the list of passed in parameters, then both will be 7.

Comment: actually what I i have is a form where i should fill the inputs : first input belongs to tab1 (the col isin't in tab2) and then the other inputs belongs to tab2, what im trying to do is when i submit the form i want to get the fields from tab2 with the field of tab1 having the same id , so like this id from tab1 is the one who filled the rest of the form

Comment: i tried this query in pgadmin4 it works fine i get the data inserted in both tables correctly

Comment: How did you do it in pgadmin4?  I don't believe it offers prepared statements.

Comment: i didn't uses $ obvly, i put in real data , now i did what u told me changed the from $2 till $8 ($1 for th first value) the thing is now the form is being submitted and my tab1 is filled along side tab2 but in my col of id_tab2 i get null instead of id of tab1